# Clarification of a question in Analytical Mechanics - Hand & Fitch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, hamiltonian

In problem 11 in the first chapter they tell you to give an example of Hamiltonian that is not conserved but equals to $E$, however if $H = E$ it follows that: 
$$\frac{dH}{dt} = \frac{dE}{dt} = 0$$
and $H$ is conserved. So my question is if they meant that just in the start $H=E$ or something else?

Comment: It appear as he ask for a system where $H=E$, but the $\frac{dH}{dt}\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While total energy is conserved, like you say, the energy of an individual system need not be conserved if it is being manipulated from the outside. For Hamiltonians, this happens when you introduce a time-varying potential $V(x, t)$. Then $\frac{dH}{dt} = \{H,H\} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$.